# Захватывающие квантификаторы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка
"1010200102001020020102"

Ну и теперь ищем совпадения с помощью следующих регулярок:

1. `'/10.*2/'` найдет одно совпадение.Максимально захватывает выборку.Результат - 1 совпадение
2. `'/10.*?2/'` будет найдено 4 совпадения.Минимально захватывает совпадения.Сдесь вроде все понятно...
3. `'/10.*+2/'`;**No match!!!**Как он работает и почему нету совпадений.+ это 1 или более раз повторений.

Comment: А в чем проверяли?

У меня в glibc regcomp(...REG_EXTENDED)/regexec() все match.

Comment: я использую пхп.Может в разных языках разное поведение...

Вот есть ссылка http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html начинать смотреть с параграфа Differences Among Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers.У меня с английским проблемы.Не могу понять

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Квантификаторы:

```
{...}+
++
*+
```

Называют «жадными» или «безоткатными» потому, что они не возвращают ни одного символа который захватили, в Вашем случае `.*+` захватит весь текст до конца строки, и не отдаст ничего, а значит для двойки не осталось места.

Чтобы проще понять такой результат представьте как работает движок в случае:

```
10.*2
```

Он также захватывает весь текст до конца строки, но обнаружив, что все выражение в целом не совпало начинает уменьшать совпадение конструкции `.*` на один символ до тех пор, пока не встретит двойку справа, если же он уменьшит размер этого совпадения до нулевой длины, то это будет значить, что все выражение не совпало.
«Жадный» квантификатор не делает уменьшения размера совпадения: все что он захватил не будет отдано никакой другой конструкции в регулярном выражении.

**P.S.**
Ну и на самом деле, конечно все это утрировано и не правда. В движке происходят совершенно другие процессы, связанные с сохранением/несохранением точек возврата. Если интересно как работают регекспы внутри (ну и если Вы хотите писать на них что-то действительно сложное), то рекомендую прочесть книгу Д.Фридла «Регулярные выражения».

Comment: пытаюсь переварить...спасибо..

Comment: Потому что в поиске совпадения для конструкции:  

    .*+
Движок захватывает весь текст до самого конца и ни одного символа из этого текста он не вернёт (квантификатор «жадный»), поэтому  не осталось текста, который мог бы совпасть с тем, что следует за:  

    .*+
А значит и все выражение не совпадает, так как в нем обязательно должно быть:  

    2
после:  

    .*+

Answer (score 3):

глянул в синтаксис регулярок, нашел:

> *?     ноль или более раз ("не жадный"), то же что {0,}?
>
> +?     один или более раз ("не жадный"), то же что {1,}?

но последовательности *+ я так и не понял что вы имели в виду.

Comment: полезно,но немного я не про то...пост не удаляйте..

Answer (score 2):

да, + это 1 и более повторений. Но в вашем примере что именно повторять ?
можете написать вот так:

```
/(?:10.*)+2/
```

Так будет работать. Только вопрос болше в том, что вы хотите получить в конечном счете ?

Answer (score 0):

Выражение 10.* соответствует всей строке (после 10 до конца строки), поскольку дальше ничего нет, то ничего и не находится.

Comment: Цель выражение 10.*+2 а не 10.*